# Rails: Devise Redirect users after sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

in my rails app I want to redirect users to a path similar to `http://localhost:3000/en/profiles/first_name-last_name/edit` for this I'm using friendly_id gem, and this is my profile model

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :full_name, use: :slugged


def full_name
    (self.first_name + " " + self.last_name).titleize
end
```

and I have create a registration controller to redirect users, this is my controller

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    "/profiles/#{current_user.profile.id}/edit" if current_user
end
```

end

and this is my routes

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|fr/ do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" } 
end
```

but after sign up I'm always redirected to the root_path instead of `http://localhost:3000/en/profiles/first_name-last_name/edit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Registration controller to

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    edit_profile_path(current_user.profile) if current_user
end
```